# Equivalent of admin.php for public pages

Tags: plugins, php, admin

I am pretty new to the Wordpress API and can't seem to find what I need.

I have been searching for a way to create public pages (accessible to users without admin permission), similar to the method used when creating pages on admin.php.

Basically, I have my application for creating surveys in the dashboard, but now I want to display the actual thing to users.

I was planning on displaying a custom link using a `shortcode`, which would in-turn open a window containing the requested survey using javascript's `window.open()`. However, I can no longer connect to the database if I call to an empty page in the plugin directory. In admin.php I could also `$.post` to `ajaxurl`, but that is only accessible in the admin headers.

What method can I use to display a public page but still have most of the features of admin.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if `admin-ajax.php` and [Ajax API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) were created to be used in ajax requests, they can be used in normal http requests with no issues, just be aware that [`is_admin()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) will be true even if user is not logged and the request is done from frontend.

What you have to do is create a callback for the ajax api. In your plugin or `functions.php` put:

```
$survey_action = 'my_survey';
add_action( "wp_ajax_{$survey_action}", 'my_survey_callback' );
add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_{$survey_action}", 'my_survey_callback' );

function my_survey_callback() {
  echo "Welcome to the survey!";
  exit(); // always exit() at the end, when using ajax api
}
```

now, when you send a request to `admin-ajax.php` containing the 'action' request var set to `"my_survey"` the `my_survey_callback` function will be triggered.

So, if you now put in your browser address bar an url like

```
http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_survey
```

the server will response with a *"Welcome to the survey!"*.

Regarding using this url in javascript, yes, `ajaxurl` global variable is available in admin pages by default, however nothing prevents you to set a similar variable in non-admin pages, using [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

Assuming you javascript file is named `my-script.js` and is located in the 'js' subfolder inside theme folder, then you can enqueue the file and pass the ajax url like so:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );

function add_my_script() {
  $handle = 'myscript';
  wp_enqueue_script( $handle, get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-script.js' );
  $data = array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
  );
  wp_localize_script( $handle, 'my_script_data', $data );
}
```

Using code above, inside `my-script.js` you have access to a global object named `my_script_data` whose `ajaxurl` property will be the proper ajax url you have to use, so, you can do there something like that:

```
window.open( my_script_data.ajaxurl + '?action=my_survey' );
```

And a new browser tab will be opened showing an awesome *"Welcome to the survey!"*.

Comment: Awesome! This is much simpler than I thought. Thank you for great explanation.